# Docker container fails to run and doesn't go inside the container

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build spark processor docker image which is used for UIC559 conversion of message
When i run the docker image i get the following error message

```
sudo docker run -it test:v2 /bin/sh
inside file
Error: Could not find or load main class .bin.sh
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /bin/sh
```

This is my entrypoint file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo inside file
exec java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -cp /opc/OPCUAClientUIC559_2.1-assembly.jar $*
```

1.I tried to create the docker image with entrypoint and ran the image and i could see the jar file inside the container
2. passed the java arguments along the docker run command

```
sudo docker run -it test:v2 com.domain.uic559.opcua.OPCUAKafkaStreamUIC559
```

I am expecting this issue to resolve and enter into container and run without any error

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.1 AS build
ARG SCALA_VERSION
ENV SCALA_VERSION ${SCALA_VERSION:-2.12.15}
ARG SBT_VERSION
ENV SBT_VERSION ${SBT_VERSION:-1.3.13}
ARG USER_ID
ENV USER_ID ${USER_ID:-9999}
ARG GROUP_ID 
ENV GROUP_ID ${GROUP_ID:-9999}
# copy the root certificate for sbt and scala package to download thorugh network 
COPY ./CIdependencies/zscaler-rootca.cer /root/zscaler-rootca.cer

# Install sbt and pass root certificate
RUN curl -fsLv --cacert /root/zscaler-rootca.cer "https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v$SBT_VERSION/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.tgz" | tar xfz - -C /usr/share 
RUN \
  chown -R root:root /usr/share/sbt && \
  chmod -R 755 /usr/share/sbt && \
  ln -s /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt /usr/local/bin/sbt && \
# Install Scala and pass root certificate
  curl -fsL --cacert /root/zscaler-rootca.cer "https://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz" SCALA_DIR=/usr/share/scala-$SCALA_VERSION | tar xfz - -C /usr/share && \
  mv -f /usr/share/scala-$SCALA_VERSION /usr/share/scala && \
  chown -R root:root /usr/share/scala && \
  chmod -R 755 /usr/share/scala && \
  ln -s /usr/share/scala/bin/* /usr/local/bin && \
  echo "@main def main = println(util.Properties.versionMsg)" > test.scala && \
  echo "println(util.Properties.versionMsg)" > test.scala && \
  scala -nocompdaemon test.scala && rm test.scala && \
# Install rpm for sbt-native-packager -see https://github.com/hseeberger/scala-sbt/pull/114
  echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* && \
  apt-key adv --batch --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0E9840 && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install rpm -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  

USER root
WORKDIR /root
RUN keytool -noprompt -storepass changeit -importcert -alias zscaler -file ./zscaler-rootca.cer -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

# Prepare sbt (warm cache)
RUN \
  sbt sbtVersion && \
  mkdir -p project && \
  echo "scalaVersion := \"${SCALA_VERSION}\"" > build.sbt && \
  echo "sbt.version=${SBT_VERSION}" > project/build.properties && \
  echo "// force sbt compiler-bridge download" > project/Dependencies.scala && \
  echo "case object Temp" > Temp.scala && \
  sbt compile && \
  rm -r project && rm build.sbt && rm Temp.scala && rm -r target 

CMD sbt

COPY ./ ./

RUN sbt assembly

FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ARG DS_VERSION=0.0.0.0
LABEL Name=OPCUA_ClientUIC559 Version=$DS_VERSION git_commit=$GIT_COMMIT
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -f --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates\
        curl\
    icu-devtools=66.1-2ubuntu2 \   
        openjdk-11-jre \ 
    && apt-get clean \          
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Create a user, group and changing the ownership to access the built files as root should not be used ideally
RUN groupadd -r opc && useradd --no-log-init -r -g opc opc
RUN mkdir /opc; chown opc.opc /opc

USER opc

# Switch working directory

WORKDIR /opc

COPY --from=build --chown=opc:opc /root/entrypoint.sh /opc/entrypoint.sh

COPY --from=build --chown=opc:opc /root/target/scala-2.12.15/*.jar /opc/OPCUAClientUIC559_2.12.15-assembly.jar
RUN chmod +x /opc/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash","/opc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `docker exec` after staring the container, if it works for your case.

Comment: container itself doesn't run and exists immediately

Comment: With the code you've included, I'd probably expect the last `docker run` command to work, explicitly including the class name at the command line; what does that print out?

Comment: `docker run -it test:v2 /bin/sh` when pass the argument "/bin/sh" to your entrypoint, which it doesn't appear to be what you want. What does `docker run --rm test:v2 com.domain.uic559.opcua.OPCUAKafkaStreamUIC559` actually output?

Comment: Based on my analysis i found /bin/sh along with docker run gave me a wrong output. I had to use" docker run test:v2 com.domain.uic559.opcua.OPCUAKafkaStreamUIC559" this gave me some output.  i could enter into the container with  sudo docker run -d test:v2